# Python module can't be imported from package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a package/module structure as follows:

```
root/
├ aa
│ └──bb
│    └──b.py
├ cc
│ └──bb
│    └──b.py
```

In IPython I'm trying to import `b` from `aa.bb` like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/root/')

from aa.bb import b
```

But I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aa.bb'
```

Importing just `aa` works, as does importing `cc.bb.b`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/root/')

import aa
from cc.bb import b
```

What might be causing the module to be ignored, and how can I debug this? I suspect this is due to some mechanism at play in my IPython setup but don't know where to look.

Comment: Just tried this, and it works for me. Are you sure your path is correct? What does `os.listdir(same_path_used)` give?

Comment: The path is correct, and the files are listed as expected. I am suspecting that there's something strange going on with my IPython setup, and I've updated the Q with a more minimal case, and it really seems that my shell is treating one particular filepath differently than another.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
import aa.bb.b
```

this has worked for me, or for a specific function in b.py you can use

```
from aa.bb.b import func
```

here is also a link to another stack overflow post about a similar topic:
[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: This works (as does the methods I was employing before) with a toy example, but not with my real use case! I'd really like to learn some tools to debug this with, as I'm scratching my head about what might be causing my modules to fail importing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a different `aa` module is being loaded on startup.

In a fresh shell you can check out the imported modules with `sys.modules.keys()` and find that `aa` is already there. You can see the source location using `importlib`:

```
importlib.util.find_spec('aa')
> ModuleSpec(name='aa', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f8f5c8dd0>, origin='/not/the/right/path/aa', submodule_search_locations=['/not/the/right/path/aa'])
```

You can reload the loaded module using `importlib` after ensuring a correct `sys.path`, which should load the target module:

```
import importlib                                                                                                                     
importlib.reload(aa)

from aa.bb import b
```